# Recieving IndexError when performing CategoricalNB() using SKLearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-analysis, prediction, naivebayes

I am currently running into an index error when trying to perform a CategoricalNB using SKLearn. I am doing this for an assignment for my data class. I tried to implement some known fixes but none have worked.

For context, here are the instructions I am supposed to do. I am currently stuck on Step 4.1

*For your third reflection, you will implement Naive Bayes through sklearn's library. Using the same dataset as your previous homework, Homework 3, you will implement sklearn's Naive Bayes classifier for training and testing.

This is an individual assignment.

**Step 1:** Add a post to your Wordpress page or website at: https://umw.domains/Links to an external site.

**Step 2:** Load this dataset from [Kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/thedevastator/higher-education-predictors-of-student-retention):

**Step 3:** Select 7 categorical features/columns that you want to use as evidence. (Since they already come ordinally encoded, you do not need to recode them)

**Step 4:** Train, test, and report (reflect) on what you observe using "Forward Selection Algorithm"

**Step 4.1**: Train p different one-feature classifiers, where p is the number of features (in your case, p = 7), and see how each one does. Use f1-measure as the only criteria for selecting the best.. (But you will calculate other metrics such as: accuracy, precision, and recall) Choose as the winner the feature that works the best in isolation. Print confusion matrix for the winning feature. Give a summary.

**Step 4.2:** Now, for each of the p−1 remaining features, train a classifier with your original winner plus the new one. Choose as the winner the “best” two-feature classifier. Again, use f1-score as the criteria. Print confusion matrix for the winning feature set. Give a summary.

**Step 4.3:** Repeat this for each of the p − 2, p − 3, p − 4, . . . remaining features, finding the “best” three-feature, four-feature, five-feature, . . . classifier. Print confusion matrix for the winning feature set. Give a summary.

**Step 4.4:** Your final answer is the best of the “best.” (Out of the “best” one-feature, two-feature, etc. classifiers, choose the one with the best performance. This is the feature set you’ll declare the winner.)*

**Now here is my complete original python code:**
*Feel free to just copy and paste this, or the simpler version under this code block*
*The error is given when doing clf.predict()*

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Mar 21 15:39:24 2023

@author: nico
"""

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.naive_bayes import CategoricalNB
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
from sklearn.metrics import precision_score, recall_score, f1_score

#read dataset
df = pd.read_csv('./Datasets/dataset.csv')
#print(len(df))

#make sure there are only graduates and dropouts (no other target is allowed)
df = df[(df['Target']=='Graduate') | (df['Target'] == 'Dropout')]
#print(len(df))
#Subsample to balance the dataset
grad = df[df['Target']=='Graduate']
drop = df[df['Target']=='Dropout']
grad = grad.sample(n=len(drop), random_state=101)
df = pd.concat([grad, drop],axis=0)
print(len(df['Target']=='Graduate'))
print(len(df['Target']=='Dropout'))

#splits data into Y which contains the Target and X which contains all seven evidence columns
Y = df['Target']

#Rename categories to not have spaces in the name
df.rename(
    columns={"Mother's qualification" : "Mom_Qualification", "Mother's occupation" : "Mom_Occupation", "Father's qualification" : "Dad_Qualification", "Father's occupation" : "Dad_Occupation", "Age at enrollment" : "Age_Enrolled"},
    inplace=True,
    )
X = df[['Course','Mom_Qualification','Mom_Occupation','Dad_Qualification','Dad_Occupation','Displaced','Age_Enrolled']]


#print(df.info())
'''
The Seven Columns I selected as evidence are:
    
1.    Course -                  The reason I chose Course is because some course are much harder than others, having higher dropout rates in comparison to other courses. 
                                Thus if a student is taking a course they are probably more likely to droput.  
             
2.    Moms's Qualification -    The reason I chose Mothers Qualification is because I think it could have a substantial influence on whether or not their child graduates.
                                As if a mother has high/outstanding qualifications then there child would have more support and be influenced to follow their parents footsteps and 
                                be more likely to Graduate
                                
3.    Moms's Occupation  -      The reason I chose Mothers Occupation is because I think it could a similar influence that a mothers qualification does. Where a higher paying occupation 
                                will provide more support and opportunities to the child, thus leading to a higher chance of graduating. 
                                
4.    Dad's Qualification -     Same reasons as Moms Qualification

5.    Dads Occupation  -        Same reasons as Moms Occupation          

6.    Displaced  -              The reason I chose Displaced is because I think students who are displaced will be under more stress and thus be more likely to drop out. So it could be
                                a telling factor as to whether or not a student is likely to graduate. 
                            
7.    Age Enrolled  -           The reason why I chose Age Enrolled is mostly because I found it to be interesting and wonder if certain ages have a higher rate of dropout out.
'''

#array containing all the evidence columns
columns = ['Course','Mom_Qualification','Mom_Occupation','Dad_Qualification','Dad_Occupation','Displaced','Age_Enrolled']
k = 10

print('Number of Graduates: ',len(df[df['Target'] == 'Graduate']))
print('Number of Dropouts: ',len(df[df['Target'] == 'Dropout']))

totalf1s = []
bestF1 = 0;
bestFeat = ''
bestConfusion = []
i = 0

#Notes from talking to Professor about the error: 
    
#give one column at time then tqo then three untill you reach all seven
#ur gigving it seven columns when its only predicting one so its getting an error
#also define min categories for each column. Look at NB_Sklearn.py

#have it iterate through one time  one featrue and every time after that
#just make sure to iterate through each

#work on it over the weekend. Due date extended due to the error

#meeting w professor next week for a longer discussion


#Step 4.1   
alreadyUsed = []

#iterate through each feature within a column of the DF
for feat in columns: 
    #grabs the minimum categories for that feature
    minCats = (len(df[feat].unique())) #get the minimum number of categories for this column
    
    #Subset the evidence data to only include one column
    singleX = df[[feat]]
    #KFold cross validation that suhffles data and has 10 folds
    kf = KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True)
    
    
    #Initialize lists to keep track of scores
    f1s = []
    accuracy = []
    precision = []
    recall = []
    predicted = []
    actual = []
   # print(feat)
   # print(minCats)
    
   #loop through each fold in the cross-validation
    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):
        #Keep track of which fold the system is on
        print("Fold: ", i+1)
        i+=1
        
        #Initiallize classifier (with the appropriate min categories)
        clf = CategoricalNB(min_categories=minCats)
        
        #get training data. For the evidence get the data from the single column subset of X
        trainX = singleX.iloc[train_index]
        trainY = Y.iloc[train_index]
        
        #get test data
        testX = singleX.iloc[test_index]
        testY = Y.iloc[test_index]
        
        #Train classifier on training set
        clf.fit(trainX, trainY)
        
        
        #make predictions on the test set
        predictions = clf.predict(testX) #INDEXERROR GIVEN HERE
       
        #Record predictions and update the lists that keep track of all scores for all columns
        f1s.append(f1_score(testY, predictions, pos_label="Graduate"),)
        accuracy.append(accuracy_score(testY,predictions))
        precision.append(precision_score(testY, predictions, pos_label='Graduate'))
        recall.append(recall_score(testY, predictions, pos_label='Graduate'))
        
        #end of Kfold cross vaildation
    
    #calculates average performance metrics acros K folds
    avgF1 = sum(f1s) / len(f1s)
    avgAccuracy = sum(accuracy) / len(accuracy)
    avgPrecision = sum(precision) / len(precision)
    avgRecall = sum(recall) / len(recall)
    
    #Print score info out for a single column
    print(feat, 'Averages Summary:')
    print('F1-Score: ',avgF1)        
    print('Accuracy: ',avgAccuracy)
    print('Precision: ',avgPrecision)
    print('Recall: ', avgRecall)
    #Reset the counter
    i = 0
    
    #I append this but havent used alreadyUsed[], have this just incase
    alreadyUsed.append(feat)
    
    #If the current columns F1 score is better than the current best, the current score becomes the best score
    if avgF1 > bestF1:
        bestF1 = avgF1 #record f1 scoree
        bestFeat = feat #record feature with the best f1 score
        bestConfusion = confusion_matrix(testY, predictions) #record the confusion matrix for the best feature
print(feat, " is the best one-feature classifier.")
print("Confusion Matrix: ", bestConfusion)        
 


#IGNORE THIS: IMPLEMENTING IT ONCE I GET THE ABOVE STEP WORKING BEFORE I TRY AND CONTINUE THIS PART FURTHER
#Step 2 (havent tested this yet)       
best_feat_set = [bestFeat]
best_feat_set_score = bestF1
for i in range(2, len(columns)+1):
    best_i_feat = ''
    best_i_score = 0
    for feat in columns:
        if feat not in best_feat_set:
            feat_set = best_feat_set + [feat]
            clf = CategoricalNB()
            kf = KFold(n_splits=5, shuffle=True, random_state=42)
           #Need to finish this part once I get 4.1 working
```

However for easier reading here is the snippet of my code where I am getting an error. It is raised when calling the predict function in the second For loop (that iterates through each K-fold).

**Trimmed Code:**
*This code is the exact same as the above block, just trimmed and cleaned up for simplicity and easier reading*

```
df = pd.read_csv('./Datasets/dataset.csv')
#Subsample to balance the dataset
grad = df[df['Target']=='Graduate']
drop = df[df['Target']=='Dropout']
grad = grad.sample(n=len(drop), random_state=101)
df = pd.concat([grad, drop],axis=0)

Y = df['Target']
X = df[['Course','Mom_Qualification','Mom_Occupation','Dad_Qualification','Dad_Occupation','Displaced','Age_Enrolled']]
columns = ['Course','Mom_Qualification','Mom_Occupation','Dad_Qualification','Dad_Occupation','Displaced','Age_Enrolled']
k = 10

for feat in columns: 
    #grabs the minimum categories for that feature
    minCats = (len(df[feat].unique())) #get the minimum number of categories for this column
    #Subset the evidence data to only include one column
    singleX = df[[feat]]
    
    kf = KFold(n_splits=k, shuffle=True)
   #loop through each fold in the cross-validation
    for train_index, test_index in kf.split(X):

        #Initiallize classifier (with the appropriate min categories)
        clf = CategoricalNB(min_categories=minCats)  
        #get training data. For the evidence get the data from the single column subset of X
        trainX = singleX.iloc[train_index]
        trainY = Y.iloc[train_index]
        testX = singleX.iloc[test_index]
        testY = Y.iloc[test_index]
        
        clf.fit(trainX, trainY)
        predictions = clf.predict(testX) #INDEXERROR GIVEN HERE (during the second feature)
       
        #Record predictions and update the lists that keep track of all scores for all columns
        f1s.append(f1_score(testY, predictions, pos_label="Graduate"),)
        accuracy.append(accuracy_score(testY,predictions))
        precision.append(precision_score(testY, predictions, pos_label='Graduate'))
        recall.append(recall_score(testY, predictions, pos_label='Graduate'))
```

**Here is the Error I recieve:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "D:\Comp Sci\219\ReflectionSKNB.py", line 139, in <module>
    predictions = clf.predict(testX)

  File "D:\Comp Sci\MyAnacondaDont\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 83, in predict
    jll = self._joint_log_likelihood(X)

  File "D:\Comp Sci\MyAnacondaDont\lib\site-packages\sklearn\naive_bayes.py", line 1461, in _joint_log_likelihood
    jll += self.feature_log_prob_[i][:, indices].T

IndexError: index 29 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 29
```

The code completes the KFold Cross Validation successfully on the first column. However on the second iteration of the first for loop, I receive the index error. So it runs successfully on the first column but the second column is where the error pops up.

When I first experienced this error i went to my professor to get help. I met with him yesterday (3/25) and have been trying to implement his fixes with no avail. In our discussion, we determined the cause of the index error to be that I was not using One column in my evidence (X array) but was using all seven. So predict was trying to predict one column but was fed seven.

To solve this I created the singleX dataframe. In the code its written: singleX = df[[feat]]

Another reason the professor thought why I could be getting this error is because originally I did not define the min_categories argument when initializing my classifier.

To solve this I created a minCats variable which contains the minimum categories within a certain column in the dataframe. Thus when calling CategoricalNB() I set the min_categories argument equal to minCats.

After implementing his fixes, I still receive an IndexError.

I don't know what else I should do or could do to fix this. Ive read similar stackoverflow posts where the same error is given, but have not found any solution for my specific problem.

If someone could let me know why I am getting this error and how I could fix it, I'd really appreciate it. That way I can finally move on to the other steps of the assignment. If anymore information is needed, please let me know! Thank you in advance!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @СергейКох Sorry! This is my first stackoverflow post. I just edited the post and added a trimmed version of my original code. I trimmed and cleaned it as much as possible, so hopefully the trimmed version is easier to read and doesn't hurt your eyes as much haha! Thank you for the feedback though.

Comment: My professor was finally able to fix the error!!! Apparently the dataset was not properly encoded, and thus I had to ordinal encode all the columns again (which is odd because in his instructions it said that the dataset did not need to be ordinal encoded as it already came encoded. However I guess it wasn't properly encoded. Once they were properly encoded, the error went away, and my code runs properly!

Answer (score 0):

My professor was finally able to fix the error!!! Apparently the dataset was not properly encoded, and thus I had to ordinal encode all the columns again (which is odd because in his instructions it said that the dataset did not need to be ordinal encoded as it already came encoded. However I guess it wasn't properly encoded. Once they were properly encoded, the error went away, and my code runs properly!

Added the following lines after initializing my dataset and it now works!

```
df[['Course','Mom_Qualification','Mom_Occupation','Dad_Qualification','Dad_Occupation','Displaced','Age_Enrolled']] = enc.fit_transform(df[['Course','Mom_Qualification','Mom_Occupation','Dad_Qualification','Dad_Occupation','Displaced','Age_Enrolled']])
X = df[['Course','Mom_Qualification','Mom_Occupation','Dad_Qualification','Dad_Occupation','Displaced','Age_Enrolled']]
```